# How to ByPass Login credentials in JasperReports Server

Tags: jasperserver

I am trying to ByPass Login credentials in *JasperReports Server* 4.5, so user can login directly without entering any username and password, this I have done by passing username and password directly in URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/flow.html?_flowId=searchFlow
&j_username=jasperadmin&j_password=jasperadmin
```

Now I want to hide these user credentials, so nobody can see the username and password.

How can I hide these credentials?

Comment: You can try to implement SSO for JR Server. You can read [this post](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=112&forumid=102&topicid=44933)

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use Token Based Authentication and to encrypt the token. This [video covers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QFlOw6teF9U) the entire process.